# Java keep printing a new line in my recursive method

Tags: java, string, recursion, println

I am trying to write a recursive method to print n number of asteriks in a line and create a new line at the end.

So, TriangleOps.line(5);

would print

```
    *****
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
    public static void line (int n){
    if(n>0){
    System.out.println("*");
    line(n-1);
    }}
```

instead it prints

```
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
```

with a lot of space at the end. Can anyone tell me how to remove the line breaks?

Comment: `println` prints a newline: use `System.out.print`, and then a `println` at the base case to get the newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
System.out.print();
```

instead

`println();` method adds new line character at the end by it self

Comment: and then put a println after you are done putting out all the *s.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `println` to `print` and add a `println` at the end:

```
public static void line(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.print("*");
        line(n - 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type System.out.print(); to overwrite

println(); by doing this the method adds new line character at the end by itself